# How can I setup feedback in THTTPRIO?

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-2010

I have developed a `Webservice` and I am consuming it on Delphi.

Indy components have a `OnWork` event but I have not found anything like it in THTTPRIO.

Is there an `OnWork` event in `THTTPRIO`? I guess it uses Indy internally, but I am sot sure about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the events of the THTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode object.

Example:

```
procedure TYourClass.SomePostingDataEvent(Sent: Integer; Total: Integer);
begin
  //Do something
end;

procedure TYourClass.SomeReceivingDataEvent(Read: Integer; Total: Integer);
begin
  //Do something
end;

procedure TYourClass.SomeMethod;
begin
  YourHTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode.OnPostingData := SomePostingDataEvent;
  YourHTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode.OnReceivingData := SomeReceivingDataEvent;
end;
```

Hope this helps you!